# Insert <CANVAS> within <DIV>

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the `<canvas>` element to scroll inside the `<div>` without overlaying any part on the page. I've been trying to insert a `<canvas>` element into a `<div>` that will act as a container but the `<canvas>` is never contained.

Here's the Codepen with a live example: [CANVAS within DIV](https://codepen.io/izwicky/pen/YaXavv)

*Here's the code*

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Latino Food Show Floor Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>

<body>
    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas></canvas>
            <script src="canvas.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div id="iframecontainer">
            <iframe name="boothinfo" src=""><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
overflow: auto;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
height: 1400px;
}

#main-container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#canvas-container {
display:block;
width:69.5%;
height:900px;
float:left;
object-fit: contain;
}

#iframecontainer {
width:29.5%;
height:100%;
max-height: 1400px;
margin-top:-900px;
overflow:hidden;
float:right;
display:inline-block;
}

iframe {
margin:0;
padding: 0;
border: 1;
width:100%;
height:100%;
height: 1400px;
}

canvas {
border: 1px solid black;
width:100%;
}
```

Is there a way to append/insert the `<canvas>` into a `<div>`?

I'm I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: You haven't set any overflow rule on the container to cause scrolling.  The `object-fit` rule may also be a problem, since it'll try to shrink the canvas to fit the container (though that rule is not fully supported in all browsers, I wouldn't depend on it yet.)

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck! I swear I tried that before but didn't work... Just added the `overflow` rule and everything is fine. As for `object-fit`, it doesn't seem to affect anything for better or worse, stil, l deleted that just in case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto` to your div.

edit:
The `div` being the `div` in which you want to have scrollbars. In your case that would be `#canvas-container`.

Your `div` is not marked with `overflow` style, which means that the default is used. Default of `overflow` is `visible`, which means that the content of the container can be visible outside the parent's bounds.

Comment: While someone else answered. You were right, but some explaination would've helped. Can you edit your answer with some details and point the div you are refering? That way I can mark your reply as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I added overflow to your parent container(iframecontainer), and added a class to your iframe with a float, with, and height defined.  Hope it helps.

CSS

```
 #iframecontainer {
 width:29.5%;
 height:100%; 
 max-height: 1400px;
 margin-top:-900px;
 overflow:hidden;
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
 overflow:auto;
 }
 .iframeClass{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <iframe class="iframeClass" name="boothinfo" src=""><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```